# Regarding resolving version for plugin maven-compiler-plugin from the repositories

Tags: java, maven, nexus

[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin from the repositories [local (/root/.m2/repository), internal (http://scm0.access.nsn.com/nexus/content/groups/internal), central-mirror (http://scm0.access.nsn.com/nexus/content/groups/public/)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]

pom.xml--->file:///C:/Users/sopatil/Desktop/pom.xml

settings.xml-->file:///C:/Users/sopatil/AppData/Local/Temp/scp46182/home/rocky/SVN_CO/trunk/Settings1.xml

these are the files
please help me with the solution...

Comment: Sounds like a "proxy/network/intranet/firewall/permission" issue to me.. please check your access to http://scm0.access.nsn.com, your (system/java) proxy settings + (eventually) servers+credentials/secrets in your settings.xml..(colleagues should know;)

Comment: Sorry can you please elaborate what exactly you are trying to say..?

Comment: I assume: you are trying to set up a development environment .. so summarized, this: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-behind-proxy

Comment: I dont think so this will work..?

Comment: The previous question was closed for a reason (and now deleted i guess because i cant find my comments anymore). Add the contents of your configuration files. Or maybe check with someone else in the company who can help?